# Querying parent-->Child-->Grand child data using salesforce API

Tags: soql, rest-api, query, sobject

**Is it possible to query below data structure using salesforce OOTB API(Rest, Soap or Composite)?**

[image]

Lets assume that from account all objects below have 1:M relationship with their parents
There can be multiple orders for an account, multiple order lines for an order and multiple products per order line, multiple product lines per product.
technically the output ids of one object becomes input to another.

The problem that i am trying to is we need to send different data structures like this to external system for document creation and i am trying to check if this can be done without needing to write custom apex wrapper classes.

Based on the document template we need to define certain data structures with fields and that needs to be queried in run time.

I checked Rest API documentation and was not able to figure out how to query hierarchical data using it.

Comment: The other way to think would be from down up. You can use composite API to do 5 queries in a single call. The first query would be on Product lines where `Product.OrderLine.Order.AccountId = some Id`. The second would be on Product custom object where `OrderLine.Order.AccountId = some Id` till you reach the Account. This is assuming you have multi level relationships. There would be some caveats on number of records that can be fetched.

Comment: Can you write an elaborate answer and give some examples with salesforce links

Answer (score -2):

If you are looking to accomplish this with a single SOQL query, the answer is unfortunately no. With SOQL you can only query one level deep in a parent-child relationship.  Let's look at the Account -> Opportunity -> Opportunity Contact Role structure which replicates to three levels deep the structure you posted.  A SOQL query would look like this:

```
select id, name, (select id, name, (select id, contact.name, role from opportunitycontactroles) from opportunities) from Account
```

When you execute it, you'll get this response from Salesforce: MALFORMED_QUERY: SOQL statements cannot query aggregate relationships more than 1 level away from the root entity object.

This isn't an API-specific limitation.  You'd get this same error if you embedded this SOQL in Apex code.

Comment: This does not answer the question in anyway

Comment: You asked if you could QUERY the given structure using OOTB API...without writing custom APEX.  The answer is no, you can't, for the reason I explained.  You will need to use multiple queries to accomplish it.  You can accomplish this in Apex or some external routine that makes multiple API calls.  If this is not your question, then please clarify what it is you are looking for.